# Prove that $\max(a+x, b+x) = \max(a,b) + x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, maxima-minima

I want to prove the following simple identity:
$$\max(a+x, b+x) = \max(a,b) + x$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We look at cases:

Case 1: $a < b$. Then we have $\max(a+x, b+x) = b + x$, $\max(a,b) + x = b + x$.

Case 2: $a \geq b$. Then we have $\max(a + x, b + x) = a + x$, $\max(a,b) + x = a + x$.

So the two formulas are equivalent in all cases.

Comment: Because of symmetry, it is enough to consider the second case.

Comment: You should accept this

Comment: @JonathanHole can only accept in 1 day

Answer (score 4):

We can use
$\max(a, b)
=\dfrac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}
$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
\max(a+x, b+x)
&=\dfrac{(a+x)+(b+x)+|(a+x)-(b+x)|}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{a+b+2x+|a-b|}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}+x\\
&=\max(a, b)+x\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

It's evident that
\begin{align*}
a& \leqslant \max\{a+x,b+x\}-x,\\
b& \leqslant \max\{a+x,b+x\}-x.
\end{align*}
Thus
$$\max\{a,b\}\leqslant \max\{a+x,b+x\}-x.\tag{1}$$
On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
a+x& \leqslant \max\{a,b\}+x,\\
b+x& \leqslant \max\{a,b\}+x.
\end{align*}
Hence
$$\max\{a+x,b+x\}\leqslant \max\{a,b\}+x.\tag{2}$$
(1) together with (2) shows that
$$\max\{a+x,b+x\}=\max\{a,b\}+x.$$